# Electron Vue load script with config

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I try load script JS in URL

script file in HTML (**in html file script work correctly**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spartezSupportChat = {
        url: 'https://mypage.com',
        portal: 5,
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mypage.com/download/resources/com.spartez.jira.plugins.support-chat/frontend/js/chat.js"></script>
```

But I need load this script in Vue component, so I used [vue-plugin-load-script](https://github.com/tserkov/vue-plugin-load-script):

```
mounted() {
    Vue.loadScript("https://mypage.com/download/resources/com.spartez.jira.plugins.support-chat/frontend/js/chat.js")
    .then((response) => {
        var spartezSupportChat = {
            url: 'https://mypage.com',
            portal: 5,
        }
    })
}
```

but script can't see `spartezSupportChat` and return warningin console:

> WARNING: Required parameter "spartezSupportChat.url" not set, exiting
>
> WARNING: Required parameter "spartezSupportChat.portal" not set or not
>   a number, exiting

When I move `spartezSupportChat` before `Vue.loadScript...` I have this same warning.

Comment: By declaring the variable inside the success callback, it's not visible to the outside and will by definition only exist *after* the script has loaded. Have you tried declaring it first? `var spartezSupportChat = { ...};  Vue.loadScript(...`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I have this same warning

Comment: Hmm, you could try `window.spartezSupportChat = { ... };`

Comment: Yes, it's work. Thanks ;)